# How do I update a table showing the 25th day of the previous month?

Tags: sql, t-sql

I am working with a table that looks like this:

| dim_Date_key | period year | m_25th | Period_start_Date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 20210101 | 2021 | 2020-12-25 00:00:00.000 | 2021-01-01 00:00:00.000 |
| 20220101 | 2022 | 2021-12-25 00:00:00.000 | 2022-01-01 00:00:00.000 |
| 20230101 | 2023 | NULL | 2023-01-01 00:00:00.000 |

I need the m_25th column to show 2022-12-25 00:00:00.000.

I'm not entirely sure where to begin.

Comment: Does this answer your question: [How to find XXth day of previous month in SQL server?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/74975/how-to-find-xxth-day-of-previous-month-in-sql-server)

Comment: Somewhat, but I need to know how to update the table to be able to get the result I need

Comment: Learn Microsoft: [UPDATE (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/update-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16), only a 38 minutes read, including examples. Have fun learning SQL!

Comment: May we have the DDL for the table? Making us guess the data types doesn't help us help you.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `DATEFROMPARTS` TSQL function.

```
DECLARE @TABLE TABLE (dim_Date_key NVARCHAR(8), period_year INT, m_25th DATETIME, Period_start_Date DATETIME)
INSERT INTO @TABLE (dim_Date_key, period_year, m_25th, Period_start_Date) VALUES
('20210101', 2021, '2020-12-25 00:00:00.000',   '2021-01-01 00:00:00.000'),
('20220101', 2022, '2021-12-25 00:00:00.000',   '2022-01-01 00:00:00.000'),
('20230101', 2023, NULL,                        '2023-01-01 00:00:00.000')


UPDATE t
   SET m_25th = DATEFROMPARTS(DATEPART(YEAR,DATEADD(MONTH,-1,Period_start_Date)),DATEPART(MONTH,DATEADD(MONTH,-1,Period_start_Date)),25)
  FROM @TABLE t
```

```
dim_Date_key    period_year m_25th                  Period_start_Date
---------------------------------------------------------------------
20210101        2021        2020-12-25 00:00:00.000 2021-01-01 00:00:00.000
20220101        2022        2021-12-25 00:00:00.000 2022-01-01 00:00:00.000
20230101        2023        2022-12-25 00:00:00.000 2023-01-01 00:00:00.000
```